# React Native só funciona com 2 cliques

Tags: javascript, funções, click, redux

Nesse código, a função só funciona depois de ser chamada duas vezes.

```
  ubernehmen = () => {
    this.setState({wert: ((this.state.cor*208)+(this.state.letra*8)})
    this.setState({werta: ((this.state.cor2*208)+(this.state.letra2*8)})
    //nas funções abaixo o redux é usado
    this.props.Spur0VarD({...this.state})
    this.props.Spur0VarE({...this.state})
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: false })
    console.log(this.state.werta)
}

//eu chamo a função assim:
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.ubernehmen}></TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score -1):

Talvez sua função esteja demorando muito tempo para ser processada, ou pode estar com algum erro de lógica, tente debugar a aplicação para ver onde está o gargalo

Comment: se ela estiver levando muito tempo para ser processada, o que eu poderia fazer ? Eu trouxe um exemplo do app, mas isso ocorre várias vezes pelo app, mas em certos lugares funciona normalmente, as vezes mesmo esse código ai funciona.. é totalmente imprevisível.

Comment: Tente trocar o TouchableOpacity por um Buttom, importando dentro da lib do react-native - import { Buttom } from 'react-native'

Comment: troquei para Button, e acontece o mesmo comportamento.. Existem outras perguntas relacionadas mas a resolução sempre é muito direcionada, tentei fazer com componentwillupdate, mesmo estando deprecated, o qual resolveu meu problema mas quando uso no Modal ele não permite, e a aplicaçãoi é centralizada nos modais.